# Silverlight MediaElement Grayscale playback

Tags: silverlight, mediaelement, grayscale

Is it possible to playback a color video as grayscale? Ideally it would be wonderful if I could just switch there and back between the two modes instantly, just like applying a filter to the render engine.

Any ideas, experiences about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this may be possible in Silverlight 3 and above using the Pixel Shaders functionality more info can be found here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/synergist/archive/2009/05/14/alpha-video-with-silverlight-3-pixel-shaders.aspx and here http://forums.silverlight.net/t/135717.aspx/1

Comment: Hmm, not the easiest solution I was hopping for, nevertheless it's a really good one, doable, although requires quite much work.